# How i can get selection model from one method to another metod from other class with Table View?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I want to get one selected model with name, author,key_words to next window. Where it will be in tex fields. After i changing this, i want to save it in database by SQL Update command

```
public void displaySelected(ActionEvent mouseEvent) {

    ModelTable selection = Table_View.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
    if (selection == null){
        System.out.println("not selected");
    }else {
        String SelectedAuthor = selection.getAuthor();
        String SelectedName = selection.getName();
        String SelectionWord = selection.getWords();

        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("Admin_Change.fxml"));
        try {
            loader.load();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Change_Add_Button.getScene().getWindow().hide();
        Parent root = loader.getRoot();
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        stage.show();
        System.out.println("Change display");
    }
}
```

I want to set text field from selected item to new page to
Controller_Admin_Change

```
@FXML
private TextField Change_AdminEdit_Author;

@FXML
private TextField Change_AdminEdit_Name;

@FXML
private TextField Change_AdminEdit_Word;
```

Maybe its common mistake of OOP, but idk how to find a solution
Thanks for advice

Selected item what i what to insert
[From this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEfST.jpg)

to this fields
[To this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6BW4.jpg)

Comment: Have a look at this also. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32342864/applying-mvc-with-javafx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get a reference to the controller via method [getController](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/18/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader.html#getController()) in class `javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader`. Then you can invoke methods of the controller class.

Add a method for setting the text of `Change_AdminEdit_Author`, in the controller class:

```java
public void setAuthor(String text) {
    Change_AdminEdit_Author.setText(text);
}
```

Call the method from `displaySelected` method:
(Note I assume that your controller class is named `Controller_Admin_Change`)

```java
Controller_Admin_Change controller = loader.getController();
controller.setAuthor(SelectedAuthor);
```

It is recommended to adhere to [Java naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html). The below code is the same as the above code but the names are according to the conventions.

```java
public void setAuthor(String text) {
    changeAdminEditAuthor.setText(text);
}
```

---

```java
String selectedAuthor = selection.getAuthor();
ControllerAdminChange controller = loader.getController();
controller.setAuthor(selectedAuthor);
```

Comment: Thanks for response, sorry its just my first time asking community about way to find a solution